# Find and Replace with JQuery

Tags: jquery, replace

I am trying to use JQuery to search and replace all instances of a given string. JQuery was the only method I found which doesn't force-reload the whole page. This is what I have right now:

```
<script>
$("*").each(function () { 
   if ($(this).children().length == 0) { 
      $(this).html($(this).html().replace('0101','0102')); 
   } 
});
</script>
```

Right now, this replaces *most* instances of 0101 with 0102 on the page, but it does not replace instances within href links. Does anyone know why? I really need this to find/replace the whole document, through and through.

Answer (score 1):

Add this

```
$(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').replace('0101','0102'));
```

The .html() method is only going to replace the html within an element.

.attr() allows you to access the attributes of an element which of course the href is.

Comment: he is using `$(this).html()` witch would return the element as text such as `<a href="...">...</a>` there for it would replace correctly.

Comment: This didn't work. At what point exactly do I add this code in? Could you post the whole code you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your problem lies in the use of `.replace()`. If you use a string as the search-value, only the first occurrence is replaced. You need to use a regular expression  with the global-flag for this:

```
$(this).html($(this).html().replace(/0101/g,'0102'));
```

Comment: Have a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/2BKnz/ I think selecting the body will fit your intention. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: When I put this code into my site, it goes through an infinite loading loop.

Comment: Interesting problem. Can you provide a link to this site?